# How to join two CSV files?

Tags: linux, csv

Suppose you have one CSV file with 2 fields: ID and email.  You have another file with 2 fields: email and name.  How can you produce a file with all three fields joined on email?

Comment: A little more detail on the join (i.e., inner, outer, left).  Is the email list on the 1st CSV **identical** to the second list?  Or does one contain more?

Comment: Examples of the csv files would be handy to, along with the OS you are using?

Comment: i think 1st and 2nd list are identical.
I am using Linux. 

Please help!!! thanks!! :)

Comment: how large is the data?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Revision3**:

You must sort both lists on email alphabetically, then join.  Given that the email field the 2nd field of file1 and the 1st field of file2:

```
sort -t , -k 2,2 file1.csv > sort1.csv
sort -t , -k 1,1 file2.csv > sort2.csv
join -t , -1 2 -2 1 sort1.csv sort2.csv > sort3.csv
```

parameter meaning

```
-t ,   : ',' is the field separator
-k 2,2 : character sort on 2nd field
-k 1,1 : character sort on 1st field
-1 2   : file 1, 2nd field
-2 1   : file 2, 1st field
>      : output to file
```

produces

```
email,ID,name
email,ID,name
...
```

sorted by email alphabetically.

Note that if any email is missing from either file it will be omitted from the results.

Comment: CSV is more complicated than this. The field separator can be escaped for example.

Comment: @hyperslug can i do full outer join?

Comment: This won't work if the CSV is mixed quoted/unqoted, if the ID contains a comma. Use this solution only for one-time processing where you check the result. But I recommend not using it for a production-level script.

Answer (score 42):

Use [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/):

```
csvjoin -c email id_email.csv email_name.csv
```

or

```
csvjoin -c 2,1 id_email.csv email_name.csv
```

Comment: Why isn't this the top answer?

Comment: awesome tool. Even recognized, that one of my files has a different than "," delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this exists!

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it is overkill, but you could import into a database 
(e.g. OpenOffice Base) as two kinds of tables and define a 
report that is the desired output.

If the CSV import is a problem, then a spreadsheet program 
(e.g. OpenOffice Calc) can do the import. The result can 
then easily be transferred to the database.

Answer (score 3):

As a future reference you might want to start playing around with [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). It's a very simple little scripting language that exists in some form on every *nix system and its sole mission is life is the manipulation of standard delimited textual databases. With a few lines of throwaway script you can do some very useful things. The language is small and elegant and has a better utility/complexity ratio than anything else I am aware of.

Comment: Perl is in many ways a successor of awk.

Comment: awk doesn't handle quoting and escaping (e.g. dealing with ,s in a ,-separated CSV file) as far as I know.  If you need that, using a dedicated CSV handling library is easier; they exist for many languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the CSV file with a spreadsheet program like LibreOffice and use `VLOOKUP()` macro to search for the name in second file.

Comment: File extension xlsx implies Microsoft Excel and I think VLOOKUP does as well. This question is tagged with Linux. Is Microsoft Excel available for Linux?

Comment: Now LibreOffice has [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Go: https://github.com/chrislusf/gleam

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "os"

    "github.com/chrislusf/gleam"
    "github.com/chrislusf/gleam/source/csv"
)

var (
    aFile = flag.String("a", "a.csv", "first csv file with 2 fields, the first one being the key")
    bFile = flag.String("b", "b.csv", "second csv file with 2 fields, the first one being the key")
)

func main() {

    flag.Parse()

    f := gleam.New()
    a := f.Input(csv.New(*aFile))
    b := f.Input(csv.New(*bFile))

    a.Join(b).Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s,%s,%s\n").Run()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [CSV Cruncher](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher).

It takes CSV files as SQL tables and then allows SQL queries, resulting in another CSV or JSON file.

For your case, you would just call:

```
crunch -in tableA.csv tableB.csv -out output.csv \
   "SELECT tableA.id, tableA.email, tableB.name 
    FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB USING (email)"
```

The tool needs Java 8 or later.

Some of the advantages:

- You really get CSV support, not just "let's assume the data is correct".
- You can join on multiple keys.
- Easier to use and understand than `join`-based solutions.
- You can combine more than 2 CSV files.
- You can join by SQL expressions - the values don't have to be the same.

*Disclaimer:* I wrote that tool. It used to be in disarray after Google Code was closed, but I revived it and added new features as I use it.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash 5.0.3 with GNU Coreutils 8.30 and building off of [hyperslug's answer](https://superuser.com/a/26869):

If you have unsorted CSV files with duplicate lines and don't want to omit data due to a missing field in a line of either `file1.csv` or `file2.csv`, then you can do the following:

Sort file 1 by field 2 and sort file 2 by field 1:

```
( head -n1 file1.csv && tail -n+2 file1.csv | sort -t, -k2,2 ) > sort1.csv
( head -n1 file2.csv && tail -n+2 file2.csv | sort -t, -k1,1 ) > sort2.csv
```

Expanding on hyperslug's parameters:

```
-k 2,2     : character sort starting and stopping on 2nd field
-k 1,1     : character sort starting and stopping on 1st field
head -n1   : read first line
tail -n+1: : read all but first line
(  )       : subshell
>          : output to file
```

I had to do `head` and `tail` within the subshell `( )` in order to [preserve the first header line of the CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14562674) when [sorting by a given field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44744800).

Then,

```
join -t , -a1 -a2 -1 2 -2 1 -o auto sort1.csv sort2.csv > sort3.csv
```

Expanding on hyperslug's parameters:

```
-t ,    : ',' is the field separator
-a1     : Do not omit lines from file 1 if no match in file 2 found
-a2     : Do not omit lines from file 2 if no match in file 1 found.
-1 2    : file 1, 2nd field
-2 1    : file 2, 1st field
-o auto : Auto format: includes extra commas indicating unmatched fields
>       : output to file
```

Here is an example `file1.csv`, `file2.csv`, and the resulting `sort3.csv`:

`file1.csv`:

```
ID,email
02,bob@test.com
03,frank@test.com
05,sally@test.com
07,raul@prueba.eu
11,zulu@xi.com
```

`file2.csv`:

```
email,name
tim@test.com,Timothy Brown
bob@test.com,Robert Green
raul@prueba.eu,Raul Vasquez
carol@google.com,Carol Lindsey
```

`sort3.csv`:

```
email,ID,name
bob@test.com,02,Robert Green
carol@google.com,,Carol Lindsey
frank@test.com,03,
raul@prueba.eu,07,Raul Vasquez
sally@test.com,05,
tim@test.com,,Timothy Brown
zulu@xi.com,11,
```

You can see Timothy Brown  and Carol Lindsey  lack IDs but are still included in the joined CSV file (with their names and emails in the correct fields).

Answer (score -1):

You could also use a tool specifically designed for joining csv files, such as the one found on https://filerefinery.com

> The operations we currently support are: Joining csv files. It is possible to perform the SQL equivalent of outer, inner, left and right join operations on two csv files. Which column will be used as a join key in each of the files is configurable.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: No longer exists.